# How to insert element in array in the middle

Tags: php

I don't know, ow to insert element in array in the middle with php. I know how it's solve in c++ or c#, but in php i don't know.
Please help me.

I used

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
print_r($stack);
```

but this add in begin of array not middle.

Comment: I guess you need to use key for that.

Comment: Use `array_splice()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_splice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
array_splice($stack, 1, 0, array("apple", "raspberry"));
```

Specifying a length of `0` means it should just insert the new elements at that position, without removing anything.

If you're just inserting a single element into the array, you don't need to wrap it in an array:

```
array_splice($stack, 1, 0, "apple");
```

Comment: if i have only one array and i want insert value in this array ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
$inserted = array("apple", "raspberry");
$position = 1;
array_splice( $stack, $position, 0, $inserted );
```